# How to get month and year from dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss ms?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have a table with two columns.

It looks like this:

```
TIME ID
13/12/20 13:43:23,87615000 1234
22/02/21 00:49:53,00143512 5678
```

I now want to get a new column MONTH_YEAR. The new table should look like this:

```
TIME ID MONTH_YEAR
13/12/20 13:43:23,87615000 1234 12/20
22/02/21 00:49:53,00143512 5678 02/21
```

How can I do this in SQL?

EDIT: I am using Oracle SQL.

Comment: 1) Please tell us your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.), and 2) please also stop storing your dates inside text columns.

Comment: What data type is your `time` column - is it actually a string, or is it a timestamp and that's just how your client is formatting the output (e.g. via `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`)?

Comment: It is already a timestamp. I solved it using: `to_char(TIME, 'MM-YYYY') "MONTH_YEAR"`

Answer (score 2):

Use a virtual column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  TIME       TIMESTAMP,
  ID         INTEGER
             CONSTRAINT table_name__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  MONTH_YEAR VARCHAR2(5)
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CAST( TO_CHAR( time, 'YY/MM' ) AS VARCHAR2(5) ) )
);
```

Which, for your data:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( time, id )
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-12-13 13:43:23.87615000', 1234 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-02-22 00:49:53.00143512', 5678 FROM DUAL;
```

Then the table contains:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

> ```
> TIME                         |   ID | MONTH_YEAR
> :--------------------------- | ---: | :---------
> 13-DEC-20 01.43.23.876150 PM | 1234 | 20/12     
> 22-FEB-21 12.49.53.001435 AM | 5678 | 21/02
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cd78c2d3cc164c23d3fb2196eb4848a8)*

Comment: `'YY/MM'`?  Did you never hear about the Y2K bug?